# Jekyll include whole sass directory in destination folder

Tags: jekyll

I'm using jekyll and gulp for my project. What I want is to include the whole sass directory (with all the partials that use underscore in names) in jekyll destination directory. Is it possible? Include directory in _config.yml only copies files without underscores, and resulting css file without source sass files is practically non-manageable and the client wouldn't be able to change the css

Answer (score 0):

In your `_config.yml` add

```
include: ['_sass']
```

Rename your sass files from `_base.scss` to `base.scss` removing the underscore to avoid exclusion.

Now all files in `_sass` will be copied to `destination` (eg: `_site`).

Comment: Thanks, but my point is, how can I avoid underscored files to be excluded

Comment: Only by putting them in the `include` array.